# JFreeChart XYAreaChart make areas start at smallest y-axis instead of 0

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to create an `XYarea` chart; but instead of the areas revolving around the 0 y-axis, I would like them to start from the bottom the smallest y-axis (-10 here).
Here is the original graph from the `JFreeChart` example.

[image: StackedXYAreaChartDemo2]

My desired results are something like this:

[image: Desired Graph]

I have tried  both `XYarea` and `SstackedXYArea` charts.

Comment: See also discussion [383](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/discussions/383).